# How to dynamically change a UITableViewCell's tag when cells in rows before it get removed?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

UPDATE:  I have solved this problem by retagging remaining cells in order by cycling through them in a for loop incrementing the indexpath's row every time up to the amount of data left.

I have a UITableView with 2 sections.  One section is fixed.  the other section changes dynamically, a user clicks a button and a new row is added.  The cells contain three text boxes which the user can edit (tagged 1,2, and 3).  The rows in this section are editable and a user can swipe and delete.  All of this functionality is currently working fine. Here is the UI:

[image]

What isn't working fine is when I am trying to update the data source.  I use an array that contain objects of a custom class called "ReceiptItem".  When a user edits one of the UITextFields in a cell, I am updating the corresponding property in "ReceiptItem".  I am currently using tags to track which cell and text field is being edited.

The code where I identify what cell and textfield are being edited is:

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    //find the cell and textfield that just ended editing
    int row = textField.superview.tag;
    int column = textField.tag;

    ReceiptItem *itemToBeUpdated = [[ReceiptItem alloc]init];
    itemToBeUpdated = [receiptItemsArray objectAtIndex:row];

    //update the receiptItem
    switch (column) {
        case 1:
            //quantity text field
            itemToBeUpdated.quantityValue = [textField.text doubleValue];
            break;
        case 2:
            //item text field
            if ([textField text].length == 0) {
                itemToBeUpdated.itemName = @"Blank";
            }
            else{
                itemToBeUpdated.itemName = [textField text];
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            //price text field
            itemToBeUpdated.priceValue = [textField.text doubleValue];
            break;
    } 
    [receiptItemsArray replaceObjectAtIndex:row withObject:itemToBeUpdated];
}
```

Where I run in to problems is when a row gets deleted.  I delete the corresponding object from my datasource and my array's count goes down by one.  If I then try to edit a textfield in a cell further down from the cell that was deleted I get an "outofbounds" error because the tag for the cell is now greater than array's count.  It is happening in this line (from above):

```
itemToBeUpdated = [receiptItemsArray objectAtIndex:row];
```

I am trying to figure out how I can either a)better track the cells, b) retag the cells when one is deleted or c) something else.  Any answers?  I can post the code where I cell is deleted if needed.

Comment: After deleting your row, reload table data and retag your cells in cellForRowAtIndexPath method

Comment: Don't use tags to store state. Use the index path of the cell to get back to your data.

Comment: @CarlVeazey I would like to do that.  However, in the UITextField delegate method - (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField I only have access to a textfield.  Do you know of a way to pull the indexpath for the cell that UITextField is in without using a tag?

Comment: @IkegawaTaro since you're pulling the tag from the cell anyway with textField.superview.tag, use the `-indexPathForCell:` method on `UITableView` after you get the cell with textField.superview

Comment: @CarlVeazey Thanks! That makes sense - I am new to this and have not used the indexPathForCell: method yet.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your are taging the textField in cellForRowAtIndexPath's methods if (cell == nil) like,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

            if (cell == nil) {
                 cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]
yourTextField.tag = indexPath.row;            
            }
}
```

Make the taging outside the if block so that when you delete a row and at reload data call your textField will get new tag like this :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
                UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

                if (cell == nil) {
                     cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]

                }
yourTextField.tag = indexPath.row;
return cell;
    }
```

Comment: I am actually not tagging the textfields in cellForRowAtIndexPath but rather in IB.  I am tagging the cells in that method.  I am working on implementing the reload data call.  I think that will fix the problem.